# Difference between using withStateHandler and withState + withHandler

Tags: recompose

Does `withStateHandler` has some benefit over using `withState` and `withHandler` together?

Why should I use `withStateHandler` at all when I can get same functionality with `withState` and `withHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

`withStateHandler` has little benefits like `less code` and `fewer function imports`, but that won't do a lot of performance increment, practically they do the same thing in the same way if you do not worry about the size of your code splitting or something like this